# How to simulate discrete data from a Poisson distribution?

Tags: r, machine-learning, missing-data, ecology

I want to use R to simulate discrete data with missing values from a Poisson distribution.
I have tried this: `simdata<-rpois(1000,2)` but when I checked if there are missing values, there were none.

Comment: So, most statistical software has built in functions for this. What software would you like to use?

Comment: I am using R. I want the simulated data set with missing values.

Comment: Wait... You want to simulate missing data?

Comment: I am using R. I want the simulated data with missing values. I have tried this: simdata<-rpois(1000,2) but when I checked if there are missing values, there were not.

Comment: Yes, I want to simulate missing data.

Comment: Of course a built in simulation function will not generate missing values. Consider generating another vector from a binomial distribution n=1000, p=0.99. Then, replace the 0's in that vector by NA, and elementwise multiply the vectors to get a Poisson random variable vector  with missing values.

Comment: You have to define a distribution for the missing data, from the probability of missing to the fact that it is missing at random or not (then depending on the realisation).

Answer (score 2):

Simulating from a Poisson distribution in R: use rpois(n, lambda), with lambda the mean of your process and n the desired length of the vector.